# Why is (++it) valid for a std::multiset::iterator, but (it + 1) isn't?

Tags: c++, iterator

```cpp
int main(){
        multiset<string> graph;

        graph.insert("a");
        graph.insert("b");
        multiset<string>::iterator it = graph.begin();
        cout << *(it + 1) // Wrong
        cout << *++it;    // True
}
```

why does the compiler complain when executing `*(it + 1)`, but `*(++it)` can be well executed. Shouldn't `it + 1` and `++it` return the same value?

Comment: There are different kinds of [iterator categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator#Iterator_categories). Not all iterators support all operations.

Comment: If you don't know how long a step is, there's a difference between "ask Paul to take one step forwards" and "tell me where Paul would be if he took one step forwards".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RandomAccessIterators allow you to add arbitrary offsets like `it + n`, but `multiset` has only BidirectionalIterators. For more on iterator categories see here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator#Iterator_categories.

In principle you are correct, that `it+1` and `++it` both increment the iterator by one. And if an iterator supports `++it` it could also support `it+n`. However, the idea is that RandomAccessIterators can perform `it+n` in constant time, while iterators that are not RandomAccessIterators would need to perform n-times single increments. Because that is rather inefficient they do not support it out of the box.

If you want to increment a non-RandomAccessIterator by more than `1` you can use [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) or [`std::advance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance). By calling `std::next`/`std::advance` the code more clearly expresses that incrementing the iterator is a potentially expensive operation, while `it + n` is expected to take constant time (hence not allowed when it does not take constant time).

Answer (score 4):

Because `std::multiset` iterator needs to satisfy requirements of [BidirectionalIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator), which means that it must support `operator++` and `operator--`. There is no requirement to support other operations, like addition or subtraction.

Answer (score 2):

An iterator is an object that fit with the structure, each iterator works differently depends on what structure you're using (map, set, vector,..).

An iterator is defined with functions, in C++ you can overload operators like +,-,*,(),[],... , so maybe ++ function as been defined not like the operator
`+(iterator, int)` which result an error.

Answer (score 2):

If you support `+ 1`, you have to also support `+ N`. To make it harder to write inefficient code, `+ N` is only supported for iterators for which it works in constant time (e.g. it's supported for `std::vector`).